# Используется ли в крупных проектах отправка Git-патчей через электронную почту?

Tags: git

Изучаю возможности Git и узнал, что можно с помощью Git сделать патч-файл и отправить по почте, т. к. под капотом это обычный текстовый файл.

У меня вопрос: **Используется ли отправка патчей для Git по электронной почте в крупных проектах и как именно?**

С одной стороны, в материале сказано, что иногда возникает ситуация, когда у человека, которому нужно применить (или отправить) изменения может быть заблокирован корпоративным файерволом даже http, не говоря уже про протокол git, а электронная почта, скорее всего, есть у всех.

Так-то звучит разумно, но в любом серьёзном проекте должно быть настроено всё нормально. Это же просто очень дорого - тратить силы и время разработчиков на упаковку и менеджеринг патчей.

Comment: В Linux используется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная возможность была добавлена потому, что сам проект Linux (авторы которого создали git под себя) использует данный способ.

Особенность разработки ядра Linux состоит в том, что в этом открытом проекте есть очень много доработок не от постоянных контрибьютеров, а от людей создавших только один патч. По этой же причине у коммита два автора. Тот кто произвёл изменения, и тот, кто внёс их в центральный репозиторий.

Члены основной команды, естественно, этим способом давно не пользуются. Ну разве что крайне редко откуда-нибудь из отпуска, где интернет слабый.

Таким образом ответ на поставленный вопрос: Да, используется. Но не для основной команды, а для приёма сторонних патчей.